# What would be the modern equivalent for 2001 Specialized RockHopper?

Tags: mountain-bike, parts, specialized-bikes

My beloved and dependable 2001 Specialized RockHopper A1 were stolen by some lowlife about two weeks ago. After filing a complaint with the local police dept. I filed a claim with my insurance company. They ask for a valuation of a replacement bikes.

Looking at the Specialized website I was kind of amazed to see how the variety of bicycle types and models grew with the years. It is a whole zoo, and it really is hard to tell the differences between models in different but similar categories (but that's probably for another question).

My stolen RockHopper had aluminum frame, 26" wheels, Shimano Deore / Deore-LX derailleur, RockShox Judy front suspension, V-brakes, thin metallic pedals, and that's what I remember in terms of components.

The current entry level RockHoppers offer SR Suntour fork, Altus & Tourney derailleurs and more entry level components.

**What model would be considered the equivalent to my old RockHoppers?**

Comment: Are you perusing this through contents insurance or a dedicated bike insurance? New for old or a value limitation ?

Comment: @DanK - I am not sure about the name, but I believe this is contents insurance (i.e., tenant's home insurance)

Comment: A visit to the local Specialized dealer, and the manager estimated a new replacement would be somewhere $1,100 - $1,500.

Comment: The insurance were nice enough to approve the lower estimate (less my deductible), which proves that it is always good to try!

Answer (score 1):

> RockHopper had aluminum frame, 26" wheels, Shimano Deore / Deore-LX
> derailleur, RockShox Judy front suspension, V-brakes, thin metallic
> pedals.

I would consider this as mid-range from that era.

Judy forks have remained consistant in their pecking order (give or take) for all this time.

Similarly for Deore / LX. Could argue that LX is closer to modern SLX or even XT. But given that it was a mix before, it would be a mix now. IE not soley high-end.

I personally think that a modern replacement (like for new) would be either the Rockhopper Comp or maybe the Elite. (Deffo not the Expert).

Whether you choose the Comp or the Elite, is up to you. There really isn't much between them in terms of components, and there are arguments for either to be a match for your old one.

Comment: Thanks for the information. This seems to make sense. One of the coming days I hope to get myself to the local Specialized dealer, hopefully it is open, and get their opinion, as suggested in another comment.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to hear about your loss.

A bicycle that is 19 years old is unlikely to be covered by home insurance, as its value has been diminished to zero in eyes of an insurance company. Even if you have saved receipts, inflation has certainly reduced the amount of money you would get to a microscopic value not covering a cost of a new bicycle. Unless you have insured the bike separately (e.g. as a vintage object); in this case, its value is known and is explicitly written in the contract.

For any number you would show to the insurance people, they would ask for a justification on how you got the number. Just saying that "2020's model X is an equivalent to 2001's Rockhopper" without an independent estimation is unlikely to work.

If they do not ask you for a justification of your valuation, why don't go with the most expensive bicycle in the category? An insurance company that does not verify its customers' claims would soon go under, however.

Comment: Thanks for the input. This would really be a comment, not an answer. The claim form clearly asks the replacement value. My agent did not disregard my questions about this, even though he knew all this information. You go with the most expensive - you get nothing. You give an honest estimate - maybe you'll get something. At the worst case, I wasted an hour and the forum's time.

Comment: Maybe @ysap should ask a Specialized dealer for a valuation, then. This worked for me in an auto insurance claim before, and I believe that it should be generally applicable. I would expect the LBS to identify a current model that's equivalent to where the Rockhopper was in the 2001 lineup. Deore and LX are the mid range groups, which I think are roughly equivalent to the 105 road group. Presumably the store would identify a cross country hardtail with similar level components.

Comment: @WeiwenNg Sounds nice. I wonder if looking at the local used bicycles web market for similarly aged Rockhoppers could also be used to estimate the value of the stolen one. Or, as it sometimes happen, one can sometimes find the very stolen bike now being for sale...

Comment: If the insurance company decide to use the bluebook value the value is only around $150 as a private sale and $50 for a trade value. I know some insurance companies are very vague when it comes to valuations, hence why I have separate bike insurance.

Comment: If it's being claimed as stolen property under a homeowner's/tenants policy many such policies in some countries are in fact "replacement cost" and pay what it costs to buy a new similar one, not the stolen item's current market value like automobile insurance would pay.

Comment: @GrigoryRechistov - There is no doubt that today's value is very low. In my local Craigslist, the usual asking price for such bicycles, and similar Treks would be around the $150-$300 considering condition. As for fniding the stolen ones - I asked the officer that came to my home if they ever find stolen bikes. He surprised me by saying that they actually do. Many times those bikes are just being dumped and they have a yard full of found bikes. Fortunately, I had the frame serial number to give him, but at this point I stopped hoping they will be found.

Comment: @DanK - I have a policy rider for my photo equipment for that reason. It never ocurred to me to insure the bicycles separately, because my perception was their low value (way below my deductible). If and when I get a new pair, I'll make sure to verify this point with my agent.

Comment: As an anecdote, a few months before I bought this pair in 2001 (I lived in another country at the time), I boughth a nice pair of Haro MTBs, which were stolen in broad daylight at the city square, from a place where an officer was regulating traffic at the busy traffic circle... Luckily, our home insurance policy covered the theft and paid a full price of new bike. I used that money to fund the part of the RockHoppers, which where 3x more expensive. At least those lasted for some 19 years of fantastic service. Worth every penny.

Comment: Updated question comments section.